# #1072 key column doesn't exist error with MySQL foreign key

Tags: mysql

I've searched for answers might work, but didn't fix.

I've created tables like this and when created table 'hobbies' got error 1072.

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project_r`.`user` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `RealName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `FamilyName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `birthdate` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `Homecity` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `school_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `school_enteryear` INT NOT NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `activestat` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `onlinestat` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `regtime` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  `avatar` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `status` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `desc` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `self_comment` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `userMsg_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_user_school1_idx` (`school_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_school1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`school_id` )
    REFERENCES `project_r`.`school` (`school_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

then and create table 'hobbies'

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project_r`.`hobbies` (
  `hobby_user_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `favorite_music` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `favorite_game` VARCHAR(20) NULL ,
  `favorite_film` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `favorite_book` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `favorite_sport` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `favorite_cartoon` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `hobby` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_user_id` (`hobby_user_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`hobby_user_id` )
    REFERENCES `project_r`.`user` (`user_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

both AUTO-INCREMENT things added or not or index added to referenced tables didn't work.
thx for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting a `PRIMARY KEY` on a column `user_id` in `hobbies`, but there is no such column. It is called `hobby_user_id`.

```
 PRIMARY KEY (`hobby_user_id`) ,
```

A quick test in my own database successfully creates these two tables with the correct `PRIMARY KEY` spec.

Answer (score 1):

In the 'hobbies' table you're trying to set the pk to user_id, which doesn't exist. change it to:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`hobby_user_id`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Field `user_id` on table `hobbies` does not exist, 
may be you want `hobby_user_id` to be primary key in table `hobbies` :

```
 PRIMARY KEY (`hobby_user_id`),
```

Constaint foreign key on table `hobbies` there is nothing wrong.