# How to create Foreign Key using MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

After importing `MySQLdb` module I go ahead and connect to MySQl Maria db:

```
import  MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="user", passwd="pass", db="test")
```

Now I want to create two tables: `Writers` and `Readers`. I want `Readers` to have a Foreign Key attribute "Writer_id" that would point to the corresponding Writer:

```
with db:
    cHandler=db.cursor()
    cHandler.execute( "CREATE TABLE Writers(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT)")
    cHandler.execute( "CREATE TABLE Readers(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, FOREIGN KEY(Writer_id) REFERENCES Writers(Id) ) ")
```

But the code fails with the error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1072, "Key column 'x' doesn't exist in table")
```

Where is the error?

Comment: 1072 looks similiar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812863/1072-key-column-doesnt-exist-error-with-mysql-foreign-key, doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_key_column_does_not_exits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with db:
    cHandler=db.cursor()

    cHandler.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Writers")
    cHandler.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Readers")

    cHandler.execute("CREATE TABLE Writers(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name TEXT)")
    cHandler.execute("CREATE TABLE Readers(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name TEXT, Writer_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(Writer_id) REFERENCES Writers(Id))")
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create writer_id in Readers table first and then set it as a foreign key after.

```
cHandler.execute( "CREATE TABLE Readers(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, Writer_id INT ) ")
cHandler.execute( "alter table Readers
add foreign key (Writer_id)
references Writers(Id)")
```